# Why does the params "id" key change from params[:id] into params[:model_id]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I go to the characters controller, show action, all the normal params[:id] is as how it should be according to REST.

In the show view, I render a partial. In that partial, I have a link that goes to the `vote_socionics` action. This action is defined under a `socionics_votes` module, which gets included by the characters controller. (I have it set up this way because I have other controllers that also include this module).

My problem is that when I click on this link, and it goes to the `set_votable` private method within the `socionics_votes_module.rb` file, the `params[:id]` is no longer present. Using pry, I found that it actually turns into `params[:character_id]`

**Questions:**

1) Why does this happen (is it because it goes to a "different" controller, even if it's a module?)

2) How do I work around this? I would think that it would be more elegant to have it be params[:id], instead of having to do an if-else to account for both keys.

**characters_controller.rb**

```
class CharactersController < ApplicationController
  include SocionicsVotesModule

  def show
    @character = Character.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**characters/show.html.haml**

```
= render partial: 'votes/vote_socionics', 
  locals: { votable: @votable, votable_name: @votable_name, socionics: @socionics }
```

**_vote_socionics.html.haml**

```
= link_to content_tag(:div,"a"), send("#{votable_name}_vote_socionics_path", votable, vote_type: "#{s.type_two_im_raw}"), 
          id: "vote-#{s.type_two_im_raw}", 
          class: "#{current_user.voted_on?(votable) ? 'voted' : 'not-voted'}",
          method: :post, 
          data: { id: "#{s.type_two_im_raw}" }
```

**socionics_votes_module.rb**

```
module SocionicsVotesController
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :set_votable
  end

  private
    def set_votable
      votable_constant = controller_name.singularize.camelize.constantize
      @votable = votable_constant.find(params[:id])    # This is where it fails, since there is no params[:id], and rather, params[:character_id]
    end

    def set_votable_name
      @votable_name = controller_name.singularize.downcase
    end
```

**routes.rb**

```
concern :socionics_votes do
  post 'vote_socionics'
end

resources :characters, concerns: :socionics_votes
resources :celebrities, concerns: :socionics_votes
resources :users, concerns: :socionics_votes
```

The URL of the link in the partial when hovered over.

localhost..../characters/4-cc/vote_socionics?vote_type=neti

Something like `.find(params[:id] || params[:"#{@votable_name}_id"])` didn't work, and seems silly.

Comment: Pretty sure it is a routing problem. Can you show the relevant parts of routes.rb?

Comment: Is character a subresource? i.e. is the url something like: `some_resources/1/characters/1`? In this case the `id` param will be for the base resource, and the id of the character will be the `character_id` param.

Comment: Yes, it is that way, Slicedpan.

the url when hovered over the link is 

`http://localhost:3000/characters/4-cc/vote_socionics?vote_type=neti`

How would i alter my private method with `params[:id]` to account for this? A simple static string of `:character_id` won't work in my case because I have various models that include the module with actions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `vote_socionics` route as a member of the resource:

```
concern :socionics_votes do
  member do
    post 'vote_socionics'
  end 
end
```

This way the `id` parameter gets set correctly

Comment: WOOT! thank you so much!

As a note to future readers, this changed my route from `character_vote_socionics_path` to 'vote_socionics_character_path`.

This becomes another way to detect issues.

Comment: Also, why this happens (or at least an explicit explanation) can be found here in section 2.10 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html